# To convert Datetime to uniform 15 minutes format and also extract Year, Month, Day, Hour columns from DateTime

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe df as shown below:

```
Code DateTime             Reading      
801  2011-01-15 08:30:00  0.0
801  2011-01-15 07:45:00  0.5
801  2011-01-16 06:30:00  5.0
801  2011-02-05 05:30:00  0.0
801  2011-02-08 00:45:00  10.0
```

And so on for the entire year 2011. This does not a have a specific time interval. Hence i would like to fix a time interval of 15 minutes and get a continuous uniform data starting from 2011-01-01 00:00:00 up to 2011-12-31 23:45:00 and the corresponding reading should be '0.0' for all the newly added rows. Already existing readings must be retained.

Also i would like to add 4 columns Year, Month, Day, Hour which has to be extracted from DateTime column.

My output should look like:

```
Code DateTime             Year Month Day Hour Reading      
801  2011-01-01 00:00:00  2011   1    1   0     0.0
801  2011-01-01 00:15:00  2011   1    1   0     0.0
801  2011-01-01 00:30:00  2011   1    1   0     0.0
801  2011-01-01 00:45:00  2011   1    1   0     0.0
801  2011-01-01 01:00:00  2011   1    1   1     0.0
.
.
.
801  2011-12-31 23:45:00  2011   12   31  23    0.0
```

Can anyone please guide me through this?

Comment: Look at [`resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) and the [`.dt accessor`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#dt-accessor) to extract year, month, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dt accessor` for accessing year, month, date and hour from a timestamp. You can use `date_range` for getting the range of dates and set `frequency` for `15min` for a row for every 15 minutes. For the output you want you can do the following.

```
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'])
# Create a  year month, day and time dataframe
new = pd.DataFrame({"Year": df["DateTime"].dt.year, "Month": df["DateTime"].dt.month,"Day":df["DateTime"].dt.day,"Hour":df["DateTime"].dt.hour})
# Set index to datetime after concatinating both dataframes
df = pd.concat((df,new),axis=1).set_index(df['DateTime'])

#Create a time dataframe 
time_df = pd.DataFrame({"DateTime":pd.date_range(start='2011-01-01 00:00:00', end='2011-12-31 23:45:00',freq="15min"),"Code":801,"Reading":0})

#Create a data frame of year, month, day and time 
k = pd.DataFrame({"Year": time_df["DateTime"].dt.year, "Month": time_df["DateTime"].dt.month,"Day":time_df["DateTime"].dt.day,"Hour":time_df["DateTime"].dt.hour})

# Set index to datetime after concatinating both dataframes 
time_df = pd.concat((time_df,k),axis=1).set_index(time_df['DateTime'])

# Create a new dataframe concatinating previous two dataframes by specifying proper axis
orginal_df = pd.concat((df,time_df),axis=0)

# Remove the duplicates 
orginal_df = orginal_df[~orginal_df.index.duplicated(keep='first')]

#Sort the dataframe by time
orginal_df = orginal_df.sort_index()

#Reset the index
orginal_df = orginal_df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output

```
       Code            DateTime  Reading  Day  Hour  Month  Year
0       801 2011-01-01 00:00:00      0.0    1     0      1  2011
1       801 2011-01-01 00:15:00      0.0    1     0      1  2011
2       801 2011-01-01 00:30:00      0.0    1     0      1  2011
3       801 2011-01-01 00:45:00      0.0    1     0      1  2011
4       801 2011-01-01 01:00:00      0.0    1     1      1  2011
5       801 2011-01-01 01:15:00      0.0    1     1      1  2011
6       801 2011-01-01 01:30:00      0.0    1     1      1  2011
.
.
.
1375   801 2011-01-15 07:45:00      0.5   15     7      1  2011
.
.
1378   801 2011-01-15 08:30:00      0.0   15     8      1  2011
.
.
35039   801 2011-12-31 23:45:00      0.0   31    23     12  2011
```

If you want the order you can use

```
orginal_df[['Code','DateTime','Year','Month','Day','Hour','Reading']]
```

```
       Code            DateTime  Year  Month  Day  Hour  Reading
0       801 2011-01-01 00:00:00  2011      1    1     0      0.0
1       801 2011-01-01 00:15:00  2011      1    1     0      0.0
2       801 2011-01-01 00:30:00  2011      1    1     0      0.0
3       801 2011-01-01 00:45:00  2011      1    1     0      0.0
4       801 2011-01-01 01:00:00  2011      1    1     1      0.0
5       801 2011-01-01 01:15:00  2011      1    1     1      0.0
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. But im getting this error: ValueError: Plan shapes are not aligned. After time_df and k concat

Comment: Try printing the both the data frames once. It maybe caused due to lack of columns or misspelled column names .Its working fine in my PC.

Comment: Ya got it thanks. Is there a way to reset the reading column to '0' everyday at 8:45 am?

Comment: You can ask a separate question for that